# Locating records in a table where one of its field has more than one corresponding field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I hope my title is not too confusing. I am having trouble querying a table in access. I am going to use an example of what I am trying to do. I am trying to locate records where one of its field has more than 1 corresponding field. For example in the mini table I created below I want to query the ID_number field to return the ID number 3 because ID number 3 has 2 corresponding ID Code, EFG and HIJ. The table is to have 1 ID number for each ID code. If there is is more than 1 ID code for each ID number I want to see that record return in the result.

```
ID_Number   ID_Code     Adress

1            ABC        123 
2            CDE        567  
*3           EFG        897
*3           EFG        589 
$3           HIJ        215
5            LMP        532 
6            MNO        895
7            PQR        875
8            STU        312
```

Thank you all for the quick reply. But I should had been more specific because I thought the original info would had been enough but I didn't think about the address variable, sorry for not mentioning it earlier. The issue at hand is that the ID Number and ID code can have duplicate if they have different address like the ones I marked with a *. But there cannot be a duplicate of a ID number with a different ID code and address. Is there a way to query for the duplicate with the $ mark?

Answer (score 0):

Or of you want one query which will give you everything you could so something like this:

```
select * from (
select *, count(fieldname) as count from tablename 
group by fieldname
) t1
where t1.count > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick reply. But I should had been more specific because I thought the original info would had been enough. The issue at hand is that the ID Number and ID code can have duplicate if they have different address like the ones I marked with a *. But there cannot be a duplicate of a ID number with a different ID code and address. Is there a way to query for the duplicate with the $ mark?